# Mysql Procedure Partitioning table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, scheduler, partitioning

I have no idea why my script does not working!!!
I develop procedure for partitioning tables. I've run the procedure with scheduler, but partition was not created.

I want to make partition table per a month many as variable months_future in procedure.
Therefore I used 'while'.

Could any body help me??

There's a procedure.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CreatePartitions $$

-- Procedure to delete old partitions and create new ones based on a given date.
-- enough new partitions will be made to cover until (today_date + days_future)
CREATE PROCEDURE CreatePartitions (dbname TEXT, tblname TEXT, months_future INT)
BEGIN

DECLARE curdate date;
DECLARE newpart_date date;

DECLARE partition_table_name varchar(50);
DECLARE i INT;




SELECT CURDATE()
INTO curdate;

SELECT 1 INTO i;

WHILE(i <= months_future)
DO

SET partition_table_name = CONCAT('p_',CAST(((curdate + INTERVAL i MONTH)+0) as char(6)));

IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM information_schema.PARTITIONS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME=tblname
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA=dbname
    AND PARTITION_NAME = partition_table_name
)
THEN
    SET @sql := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE '
    , tblname
    , ' ADD PARTITION (PARTITION '
    , partition_table_name
    , ' VALUES LESS THAN ('
    ,'\''
    , DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(curdate, INTERVAL i + 1 MONTH), '%Y%m01')
    ,'\''
    , '));');

    SELECT @sql;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END IF;

SET i = i + 1;


END WHILE;


END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Does the above stored procedure work if you call it manually with the right parameters?

Comment: @Julia5049 Were you able to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not build more than one future partitions; it slows things down.  Just build the partition for next month the day before it is needed.  Also keep a `future` partition in case the processing fails to build the partition in time.

More discussion here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Note that about the only use for monthly partitions is if you intended to purge "old" data via the fast `DROP PARTITION` in place of a slow `DELETE`.